# How can i use if condition with laravel blade and angular

Tags: php, jquery, angularjs, laravel, angular

i pass value from `laravel` `controller` to `angular` and then show data from my `database` to `blade view laravel`. i want to try `if` condition with `angular` data from `angular` `controller` how can i do it??

i try this code:

```
 <td>
      @if(@{{pending.step1}}=='Pending')
         // here some code///
      @endif

  </td>
```

how can i use if condition with laravel blade and angular??

Comment: is `pending.step1` variable server side ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this if you need use for angular if condition :

```
<td ng-if="pending.step1 =='Pending'">
 ----------- code here -------------------
</td>
```

OR you can use laravel if condition then you should use this :

```
  <td>
      @if(pending.step1 =='Pending')
         // here some code///
      @endif

  </td>
```

Hope this work for you!

Comment: first script is working but second script not working

Comment: Error not found variable pending

Comment: so that mean we can't embed if condition from laravel with angular right?

Comment: @Heshan If you integrate angularjs in laravel framework then work both and you should use only laravel as api in pure angularjs then second script is not work

Answer (score 0):

We can use an Angular variable in blade file like this:

1. Normal use

```
Angularjs variable = data;
 @{{ data }}
```

2. Use in condition

```
Angularjs variable = data;

@if( @data == 0 )

@else

@endif
```

Comment: Hi Esd Parbodh. It is unwise to publish your email address here, except your intention is to attract all kind of spam to that address. Also it is not the concept of StackOverflow to hint at a solution and offer details only 1 to 1. Please accept the removal of your address and add the details you offer directly here. Insisting to only provide the details via mail could give the impression of an attempt to advertise your service and risks being flagged as spam. I will once again remove the address now, please understand that adding it again might be perceived as confirming the suspicion.